# Regular Expression in PHP to restrict specified characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a regular expression to make and the criteria is like this:
The string should contain `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9` and it may have any of characters like `.`, `-`, `_`. If there are any of these special characters it should happen only once.

what i want is to limit first character to be either a->z or 0-9 and not (. - _) which are allowed after first character and if there is any allowed special characters it should occur only once.

What is the desired formats are like below:

- joffinjoy = valid
- joffin.joy = valid
- joffin#joy = **invalid**
- joffin.joy_007 = **invalid**
- joffin-joy = valid
- joffin-joy_007 = **invalid**

This is what i have now.

```
<?php 
$buffer = 'joffin.joy';
if (preg_match('/[^a-z0-9.-_]/i', $buffer)){ 
echo 'in-valid characters<br/>';
}else{
echo 'valid characters<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Where exactly does your regex fail you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
'/^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[._-]{2})[\w.-]*[a-z0-9]$/i'
```

This will not allow:

- Any special character at start & end
- Any special character one after another

Comment: tried that one too... echoes "invalid characters" for joffin.joy

Comment: Edited, can you try now.

Comment: @Downoter: I will appreciate a comment here.

Comment: what i want is to limit first character to be either a->z or 0-9 and not (. - _) which are allowed after first character and if there is any allowed special characters it should occur only once.

Comment: Ah you have added 1 more condition in the question :) (Let me edit)

Comment: ok try it now. I have tested this regex on all the inputs provided by you and it seems to have worked.

Comment: thanks anubhava that worked thank you and sorry for adding one more condition in between!! :)

Comment: Anubhava how about adding one more condition like it should end with either a->z or 0-9 and not with any characters like (. - _)

Comment: oops that didn't worked anubhava infact now joffin,joy is returning "in valid characters" result :( previous reg exp was prefect one expect the last additional condition i said....

Comment: I think I mistyped. Can you try  `'/^[a-z0-9](?!(.*?[._-]){2})[\w.-]*[a-z0-9]$/i'`

Comment: @GeorgeJoffinJoy: Did you get a chance to try it?

Comment: yes i did anubhava it worked like a charm... can you tweak it one more time like what if user can enter . - _ more than one time along with all these conditions...

Comment: joffin_joy_007 is acceptable...but joffin__joy is not acceptable... like we can have any number of . - _ but those should not come at first and last and also one after the other like .., --, __ .

Answer (score 0):

How about an expression like this (not optimized but intentions should be clear)

```
'/^[a-z0-9]+[._-]?[a-z0-9]+$/i'
```

Only valid names will match this